# How to use django with sql server database from other server?

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I'm planing to built an app using Django with SQL Server. But I'm going to develop the app in my computer but the database is already exist in other computer/server.

How can I connect to that database in the other server and connect the Django which is in my computer? They are separate computers.

Comment: you can dump the database and load that data in other computers

Comment: can you give me a details please.

Comment: @AhmadEbrahim how to dump an existing database and reload it in another is 1/ specific to your database vendor, 2/ documented in your database vendor's documentation and 3/ rather OT here (it's db admin / sysadmin stuff, not programming).

Comment: And in all cases, you definity DONT want to develop directly on a production database ;-)